# IPhone 4s Not connecting to wifi at home

Tags: iphone

I just got an Iphone 4s. And I randomly one day got kicked off my wifi at home. I've done everything the internet says to to. I've restarted my phone and the network settings. I've changed the date and time. But my wifi just wont connect to my wifi at home, which is weird because my wifi works literally anywhere else but at home. Somebody please tell me something to fix this problem! Nothing I've searched up has worked and I don't know what to do!!!

Comment: Do you have any other devices at home that use your home wi-fi and do not have any problems with it? I mean, can you make sure that your wi-fi router is ok and works properly?
The other thing I would check is how your DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) is configured. Is it static or dynamic?

Comment: Every other device works other than mine.

Comment: Test to see if you can use the iPhone as "Personal HotSpot".

Comment: I havent got my phone hooked up yet so i dont have hot spot yet

Comment: And im not sure how to check DHCP

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems your router works fine - this is good. Now can you, pls, check your iPhone settings for your home wi-fi network?

On your iPhone go to Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Click circled (i) against your home network name and make sure that you have 'DHCP' selected (not BootP or Static). Then scroll down to reveal “Renew Lease” and tap on it, confirm to renew the lease when asked.

Also check that 'HTTP Proxy' below is set to Off.

Comment: My DHCP is on and HTTP Proxy is off.. Still not working

Comment: Did you try to 'Renew Lease'?

Comment: There is nothing saying to Renew Lease

Comment: Ok, so you do see your home network. It looks like you are not connected to it. In this case you should have 'Join Network' command on top. What happens when you tap it?

Comment: Password is needed so i put in the password and i know its correct because i put it in another device and it worked perfectly but everytime i put it in my phone it says "Incorrect password" but i know its the righ password

Comment: Ok. In this case you'll probably want to try to reset your router. There should be button for this on its back. Try to reset it and the connect with your iPhone again. Please, note that this will reset all router's settings to defaults.

Comment: I just restarted the router. Nothing happen. My phone still isnt connecting

Comment: Sorry for being so detailed... Did you restart by turning it off and then on again? Or did you press special 'Reset' button? It is usually very small one and may require pin to press it. It's a little bit different from restarting.

Comment: Will this effect the router itself? Will it kick off any other devises or crash anything?

Comment: It will reset router to its' default settings. As if you just unboxed it and connected to power. And yes, most probably, other devices will be required to reconnect to wi-fi again.
If this is NOT an option, then you may try to go to admin panel of your router via any browser on any device using the address: http://192.168.0.1 (most often used), enter username (admin, most common) and password. There you may wish to 'Refresh' list of connected devices. This helps sometimes.